# Convert a c# mdb solution to xml?

Tags: c#, xml, ms-access

I have a system that uses an mdb database with an xsd descriptor written in c#. Now I want to use one or more xml files with the same data instead. I have generated a couple of adapters for the mdb, but now I don't know what is needed for using xml instead. Anyone have some tips? I have managed to save the mdb as a few xml files.

Answer (score 2):

Very unclear, XML is a *very* poor substitute for a database.  I reckon you'll want to use DataTable or DataSet to load the .mdb data.  Their WriteXml() method makes it very easy to generate the xml.

Answer (score 2):

The XML is not fully substitute for relation database. The dataadapters are not supposed to work with XML files and the SQL language too. I recommend you choose another SQL database (you need propably some embeded database - such as Firebird, PostreSQL, SQLite, MSSQL CE, etc...). You can still use a OLE DB data providers (DataAdapters, DataReaders, etc...) and the data layer will need only little change because of SQL dialects.

However, if you need the data in XML, you need change whole data access layer.